# WebDriver unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: java, azure, selenium, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops

I want to run Selenium Web Driver inside Azure DevOps

```
public class ListItemsTest {

    ChromeDriver driver;
    NgWebDriver ngWebDriver;

    @BeforeAll
    public void setupTest(){

        System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers", "8.8.8.8");
        System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1", "dns,sun");

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setCapability("applicationCacheEnabled", false);
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
        ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
    }
}
```

But looks like there is no DNS service. I get error:

```
ListItemsTest.LoginTest:50 Â» WebDriver unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLV...
2020-11-18T18:29:17.7803528Z [ERROR]   LoginTest.LoginTest:96 Â» WebDriver unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What DNS entry are you trying to resolve?

Comment: Are you using self-host or host agent? If you are using self-host build agent, please make sure you have configured  network correctly.